# Как в числовой input вставить М2

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка

Есть *input* с типом *number* в котором должна быть постоянно надпись квадратного метра(м2). Плэйсхолдер убирается при вводе числа. Каким методом можно поставить квадратный метр?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: напиши рядом, справа от поля ввода. Если там number, то ввести м2 все равно не получится

Comment: @Эникейщик  тогда будет не по макету. Пока думаю о псевдоэлементе

Comment: у инпута не может быть псевдоэлемента, т.к. у него нет внутренней ноды

Answer (score 4, accepted):

пойдет?

простенько:

```css
.m2input {
  padding-right: 1.8em;
  width: 50px;
}

.m2 {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -1.5em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<input  class="m2input"><span class="m2">m<sup>2</sup></span>
```

Вариант со скриптом:

```js
function setResult(val) {
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = val;
}
```

```css
.superinput {
  border: 2px solid purple;
  padding: 0.5em;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: wheat;
  width: 100px;
}

.pseudoinput {
  height: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.pseudoinput:after {
  content: " м\00b2";
  white-space: pre;
}

.numberinput {
  border: 0px none;
  height: 1.25em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  margin-top: -1.25em;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 1em;
  outline: 0px none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="superinput">
  <div class="pseudoinput" id="result"></div>
  <input class="numberinput" type="number" oninput="setResult(this.value);" />
</div>
```

Comment: Не соответствует макету, не стоит рядом с введённым числом

Comment: когда я давал ответ, никакого "макета" в вопросе не было.

Comment: Макет появился в 15:45, вы написали ответ в 15:50

Comment: вы не думали ,что я мог начать писать ответ несколько раньше?

в любом случае - я дополнил свой ответ вариантом более подходящим.

Comment: несвоевременность - вечная драма где есть вопрос и ответ, странно что вопрос не содержит ни строчки кода, а вот претензий к ответу вагон и маленькая тележка) плюсану